# Spring 3 with spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Iam trying to create maven module using  Spring 3  with spring-data-jpa, below is pom file.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.eop</groupId>
        <artifactId>eop-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>eop-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>eop-data maven jar</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JPA Persistence + Hiberante -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda Date-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ehcache</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.envers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-envers</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MC JBoss WS native-core.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ws.native</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossws-native-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.SP11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

DataConfig.java

```
 package com.eop.data.config;


    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import java.util.Properties;

    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.eop.data.repository")
    @PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
    public class DataConfig {

        private final String PROPERTY_DRIVER = "driver";
        private final String PROPERTY_URL = "url";
        private final String PROPERTY_USERNAME = "user";
        private final String PROPERTY_PASSWORD = "password";
        private final String PROPERTY_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
        private final String PROPERTY_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";

        @Autowired
        Environment environment;

        @Bean
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            lfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
           lfb.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            lfb.setPackagesToScan("com.eop.data.entity");
            lfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProps());
            return lfb;
        }

        @Bean
        DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            ds.setUrl(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_URL));
            ds.setUsername(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_USERNAME));
            ds.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_PASSWORD));
            ds.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_DRIVER));
            return ds;
        }

        Properties hibernateProps() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");
            return properties;
        }

        @Bean
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }
    }
```

UserProfile.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profiles_data")
public class UserProfile {

    /**
     * Serial number
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2911238055543452008L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Versioned
    @Column(name = "fname")
    private String firstName;

    @Versioned
    @Column(name = "lname")
    private String lastName;
```

UserProfileRepository.java

```
 public interface UserProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<UserProfile, Integer> {
        List<UserProfile> findByFirstName(String firstName);
    }
```

SpringDataApp.java

```
package com.eop.data.main;

import com.eop.data.config.DataConfig;
import com.eop.data.entity.UserProfile;
import com.eop.data.repository.UserProfileRepository;
import com.eop.data.service.UserProfileService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration("mainBean")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.eop.data.repository")
@Import(DataConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class SpringDataApp {
    @Autowired
    UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception  {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        try {
            ctx.register(SpringDataApp.class);
            ctx.refresh();
            System.out.println("Load context");
            SpringDataApp s =  ctx.getBean(SpringDataApp.class);
            s.getAll();
        } finally {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }


    public void getAll(){
        List<UserProfile> users = (List<UserProfile>) userProfileRepository.findAll();
      // users.forEach(user->System.out.println(user.getFirstName()));
                System.out.println(users.get(2).getFirstName());

 }

    public UserProfile getById(Integer id) {
        return userProfileRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

When i ran above code ,below is the exception i have experienced .

```
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Load context
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.eop.data.main.SpringDataApp] is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125)
        at com.eop.data.main.SpringDataApp.main(SpringDataApp.java:36)
```

It is working fine when i change spring version

```
from 
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
to  <org.springframework.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
```

Note:Below are limitations that i should consider .

1. I need to develop spring-data-jpa with Spring 3.* version .
2. Spring Upgrade to higher version is  in plan but not immediately.
3. Below compiler is limitation,i can't go to 1.8 .

   1.6
       1.6

I tried with all spring 3.x versions with spring-data-jpa 1.0 to 1.6 randomly ,But couldn't work.Please suggest me the compatible spring-data-jpa version with Spring 3.x version.

Comment: When you're on the site mvnerpository.com, you should check the transitive dependencies to see what versions is used. For example, if you look at [spring-data-jpa 1.4.5.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.4.5.RELEASE) and scroll down, you will see that the Spring Framework versions it uses is 3.1.4.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

At least as a starting point, you shouldn't specify the Spring Framework version at all. 
Spring Data JPA has a dependency on it and in that dependency, it specifies the required version.

A variation of this applies to optional dependencies like Hibernate. 
Spring Data JPA has it specified as an optional dependency (because you could also use a different JPA implementation instead).
But it comes with a version as well.
So if you specify dependencies to such optional libraries, specify them without version. 
Maven will use the version from Spring Data JPA (assuming there are no conflicts).

Chances are good this approach will fix your issues.
But if you have other dependencies you might run into conflict. 
Also with the requirements, you describe I wouldn't be surprised if someone forces you to put actual version numbers in the `pom.xml`.
In such a case you can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see all the dependencies and the conflicts in your project.
You can use this information to update your `pom.xml` if you want/have to.